# handle date "2012-11-28T06:25:52.085Z"

Tags: java, date

new to java world.
so want a way to handle date 2012-11-28T06:25:52.085Z  so that I can save this in oracle DB. wnat to save in column of type TIMESTAMP
Can someone pls help

Comment: Date dt = new Date(thisdatehere); But this throws exception of invalid month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
String sDate="2012-11-28T06:25:52.085Z";
Date tempDate = sdf.parse(sDate);
Timestamp dateInTimeStamp = new Timestamp(tempDate .getTime());
```

This will directly give your the TimeStamp Object.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
Date date = df.parse("2012-11-28T06:25:52.085Z");
System.out.println(date);
```

After parsing the date string to get Date instance, you can store it into the database.

Comment: Thanks @ntalbs ...it works like charm... saved my day :) one more help ...date.toLocaleString() works for me ..but shows crossed and says its deprecated... should I not use this function ?

Comment: No. It's better not to use deprecated methods. You can use DateFormat or it's subclass SimpleDateFormat to get formatted string of Date object.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, use [Joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose:

`DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z');

Timestamp forDatabase = new Timestamp(dateFormatter.parseDateTime(myString).toDate());`